# how to connect to a shared mysql database to power bi

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, powerbi-desktop, mysql-connector

I have a database in phpmyadmin, which is not hosted in my local machine. I just have the username and password to enter in the database. link and info is below:
[image]

I want to connect the **"outreachbin"** database to power bi. for that i did the following steps:

```
1.Get Data > Database > MySQL Database
2.server:127.0.0.1:3306(also tried localhost:3306)
Database: outreachbin
3.Database:
username:phpmyadmin
password: *******
```

**got error: "MySQL: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."**
Also installed mysql connector but always getting this error. How can i solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the screenshot you posted that phpMyAdmin is hosted on server IP 54.90.3.4. Assuming the database is hosted on the same server you may want to try setting your server value to:

> server:54.90.3.40:3306

The port 3306 assumes that the database server is running on the default port.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

So, if it is the first time you are connecting to it, then you can see an icon at the home page called as MySQL. Then click on it and it will ask details. It will ask the server name, enter the name and database if required. Then it verifies and asks the username and password to login. the server Ip in your image is IP 54.90.3.4 this is your hosted server. If your database is hosted on same server, you should set your same server value. Add the default localhost in the last. [follow here to connect to powerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Ss0.png)